# Strange rendering error in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, visual-glitch

A few days ago I tried to start Visual Studio and it glitched out showing only some of the buttons and ignoring my entire project list. When I try opening a solution file, it also glitches out, showing the core components and everything being stuck in a bright white screen.

VS Menu:
[Visual Studio Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeLxF.png)

VS Editor:
[Visual Studio Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4vSp.png)

This has happened before but the only way it was resolved was by having to reinstall windows entirely.

So far I have reinstalled Visual Studio 3 times, manually installed / reinstalled all packages and libraries, Updated all graphics drivers, and searched through almost every Microsoft document and forum page for Visual Studio errors I could find.

Is there any way to fix this without having to lose all of my apps and files again?
(this only happens to 2022, I would use other versions but my projects seem to break when using them)

Comment: This isn't the first time I've seen this kind of question asked, and there doesn't seem to be a concrete way to resolve it.  All I can think of is make sure any display drivers are up to date.

Comment: Very strange. Have you filed a feedback ticket about this? That will include diagnostic information that MS engineers can use to try and diagnose the problem (in VS, _Help | Provide Feedback | Report a Problem_). Probably also worth updating your video drivers.

Comment: I already tried updating my video drivers, but after many hours of debugging I put all of my files onto an external drive and downgraded from windows 11 to windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I hit a similar issue with a WXwidgets project I'm working on, VS debug solution started to render off screen and all the buttons and text fields were all jacked, and my undo buttons weren't available.

I resolved this issue by making my file smaller, removing a bunch of commented code, white spaces about 1400 lines to 1100 lines. Idk why this fixed the issue, I just read somewhere about some issues with visual studio and files being to long.